# Netgear WNA1100 stopped working

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm facing a rather strange issue with the USB wireless adapter WNA1100.

I was able to connect to wireless using this yesterday. However, today am not.

> lsmod

shows

> ath9k_htc, ath9k_common, ath9k_hw, ath and ndiswrapper.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to the above problem, but between yesterday and today, the only change was an upgrade to Ubuntu 2.6.38 kernel, which caused the NVIDIA driver to break (I have a 7300GT), so I had to ignore that kernel, reboot into 2.6.35, and rebuild NVIDIA module from NVIDIA-Installer-270.run.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works this way, but booting into the 2.6.38 kernel shows up the wireless adapter. Booting into 2.6.35 doesn't.